# Constructor Calling

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I have a class named Node. It contains two private data. One is a string and another is a Node pointer. Now I have a constructor of this class which will contain two parameters. One is a string and another is the Node pointer.

```
 class Node
    {
        private:
            string data;
            Node *P;
        public:
            Node(string s, Node* p)
            {
                data=s;
                P=p;
            }
            ~Node();
    };

    int main()
    {
        string str="";
        Node n(str, Node* P);
        return 0;
    }
```

What is the problem with this code? And why?
I want to declare a object with this default constructor which parameter will be a string and the Node class Pointer.

Comment: by definition, a "default constructor" is a constructor without parameters, generated by the compiler if you don't provide any constructor. This is not the case

Comment: Nonsensical code is wrong code.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. Can you give us some more context?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you incorrectly using the idea of default constructor. Default constructor should not take any parameters. Here is an example:

```
class Node
{
    private:
        string data;
        Node *P;
    public:
        Node()
        {
            data="";
            P=NULL;
        }
        ~Node();
};

int main()
{
    Node n();
    return 0;
}
```

And I think that you should read more about C++ syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
Node n(str, Node* P);
```

You are using some kind of variable declaration syntax in the second argument. That is not possible.

Instead you need to declare `P` first:

```
Node* P = NULL;
Node n(str,P);
```

But the problem now is that your constructor dereferences `P` here: `p->P=NULL;`, so we need to make sure that `P` actually points to a valid `Node`. For this we have to create a `Node` first, but again the problem is that to create a `Node` we need a valid `Node` as argument to `P`. Therefore as is you cannot create `Node`s at all.

I don't quite understand your intent, but a constructor should construct the current instance of a class, not some other object passed by pointer. In `Node(string s, Node* p)` you want to fill the data members `data` and `P` with some values. And since you are passing a `string s` I guess it would make sense to assign that to `data`, i.e. `data = s`. Similarly it seems like `Node* p` should be a pointer to the parent of the current node which you want to safe in `P`, so why not assign `P = p`?